# Azure blob storage throws StorageClientException: "One of the request inputs is out of range"

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

Attempting to read from an Azure storage account running inside a Cloud Services Web role throws

```
[StorageClientException: One of the request inputs is out of range.]
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result() +96
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait() +271
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobContainer.SetPermissions(BlobContainerPermissions permissions, BlobRequestOptions options) +229
```

All of the articles I've found on the subject suggest the problem is upper-case letters in the storage connection string or blob container name.

Here's the code:

```
var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting(StorageConnectionStringConfigKey);
var blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var blobContainerName = "containername";
var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
var permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container };
blobContainer.SetPermissions(permissions);
var blobName = "SomeXmlFile.xml";
var blob = blobContainer.GetBlobReference(blobName);
var text = blob.DownloadText();
```

The exception is thrown at blobContainer.SetPermissions.

When accessing the same container using the same code and same credentials from a compute emulator, rather than from a live Web role, everything works fine. And I have no trouble reading the blob container from Neudesic's Azure Storage Explorer.

Possibly relevant: my local environment only has the June 2012 Azure SDK (version 1.7). Also, I recently upgraded the application to Postmark 1.0.14 from 1.0.8, along with its dependency Newtownsoft Json.NET (to 4.5.8 from 4.0).

I'm going to build an application line by line, without packages, just to test the connection, then add the packages in.

Has anyone seen this before when they were *absolutely certain* that all the creds and identifier strings were correctly lower-case?

Comment: It would help if you could post some code

Comment: there are other scenarios that would lead to the error - e.g., a partition key/row key with an invalid character, a date that's out of range. Those are table storage though, not blob.  You could try using Fiddler on the VM via RDP to capture the HTTP request going across.

Comment: Are you sure the container (in actual blob storage) exists? Try a `container.CreateIfNotExists()` before you try to set permissions?

Comment: General recommendation is to use Fiddler to see the request/response however since this is only happening when the code is running in your role, to debug this problem one thing you could do is catch this exception and then get the "ExtendedErrorInformation" property of the exception. This will tell you more details about the error (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.storageextendederrorinformation_members).

Comment: Could it be that you're using a different connection string for when you're running it locally (Local profile) and when it's deployed (Cloud profile)?

Answer (score 3):

Wow, am I stupid.

The problem turned out to be this: I have two settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="Cloud" ...>
  <WebRole name="WebRole" vmsize="Small">
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="MessagesConfigurationBlobName" />
      <Setting name="MessagesConfigurationBlobContainerName" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Here's the local (emulator) configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration ...>
  <Role name="WebRole">
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="MessagesConfigurationBlobName" value="LocalMessageConfig.xml"/>
      <Setting name="MessagesConfigurationBlobContainerName" value="containername"/>
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role >
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

Here's the Cloud file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration ...>
  <Role name="WebRole">
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="MessagesConfigurationBlobName" value="containername" />
      <Setting name="MessagesConfigurationBlobContainerName" value="CloudMessageConfig.xml"/>
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role >
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

I will now have a good cry and adjust my time tracking (at 3am Saturday) from "Emergency client work" to "Developer PEBCAK".

The moral of the story is, when identical code fails in one environment and succeeds in another, don't just compare the environments, compare *everything that could be different in your own code* between the environments.

Oh, and don't try to deploy software at 3am. Ever.